# How to design timer circle fill out with color(ex. Red)? Color fill out process depand on day, hour, min & sec

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, timer

I don't need static images in the background. I need like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Attractive-jQuery-Circular-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-TimeCircles/
This is good but the design does not change as per my requirement. I need a shadow effect in the design.
[image: I need this type timer.]

**My code is here.**

```js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock() {
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);
    if (t.total <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }
  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

var deadline = '2017-04-18';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

```css
.width80 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.width25 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.timer_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 162px;
}
.detail {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
}
.detail .value {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: MyriadPro-Bold !important;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #6a7090;
}
#clockdiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 80px 0 50px;
}
.detail .title {
  font-family: MyriadPro-Bold !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6a7090;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockdiv" class="time">
  <div class="width80">
    <div class="width25 timer_01">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hitraiyani/image/upload/v1482302660/timer_01_fzodnv.png" class="timer_img">
      <div class="detail"><span class="value days">00</span>
        <span class="title">Days</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="width25 timer_02">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hitraiyani/image/upload/v1482302669/timer_02_pme7wt.png" class="timer_img">
      <div class="detail"><span class="value hours">00</span>
        <span class="title">Hours</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="width25 timer_03">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hitraiyani/image/upload/v1482302666/timer_03_zrhjwk.png" class="timer_img">
      <div class="detail"><span class="value minutes">00</span>
        <span class="title">Minutes</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="width25 timer_04">
      <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/hitraiyani/image/upload/v1482302667/timer_04_h0gk94.png" class="timer_img">
      <div class="detail"><span class="value seconds">00</span>
        <span class="title">Seconds</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which shadow effect? in side the circle?

Comment: @vel behaind white circle some shadow and red color effect is  http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Attractive-jQuery-Circular-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-TimeCircles/ this type.

Comment: instead of grey color like in reference site?

Comment: Red color fill out with timer, grey is in background and behind white circle shadow.

Comment: sorry, I didnt get clear. can you make sample image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131214/discussion-between-hit-and-vel).